# MKDIR en windows

Tags: php, windows

Buenas tardes, tengo una duda:

Tengo un apache corriendo en windows.
Y tengo la siguiente sentencia:

```
mkdir("ruta...\".$reg->id, 0777)
```

Es correcto usar esa función de creación de directorio?
Tengo entendido que en windows `chmod()` no funciona, ¿es correcto eso?

También hablando de temas de seguridad... ¿es correcto asignar 0777?

**¿Debería ser más restrictivo?**

Comment: debes analizar que tipo de permisos necesitas, la pregunta **¿Debería ser más restrictivo?** es subjetiva, depende que tengas dentro de ese folder

Comment: Ok, de todos modos mi consulta era un poco más técnica, es decir, la sentencia funciona bien corriendo sobre windows? Qué hay del chmod() ?